# Attaching a file via Apex

Tags: apex

I would like to know whether it is possible to do attach a file given it's URI.

Let us assume that a file ("file.xls") is located in `"http://pubsrvr/pubfolder/file.xls".`

Is it possible via Apex to retrieve the file and attach it to a record in Salesforce ?

We have a requirement in which the client is willing to give two-column excel sheet (one containing the unique identifier of custom object and the second column containing the URI) .

They would like to know whether it is possible to attach the file (identifiable from the URI in the second column) to the custom object record id given in the first column.

The file contains ~1000 such records.

Can someone let me know whether it is possible to achieve this requirement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably set up an HTTP request in order to get your file from the remote server. Please be aware that you have to add the remote domain to the Remote Site Settings in order for the Callout to work.

Have a look here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http.htm

You can then use the loaded content to be stored into any object/Attachment. I don't know the nature of the files you have to load, and therefore if there are further consideration to take into account, like for instance for binary files transfer over HTTP.

For what regards the possibility to attach the file to the 1st retrieved row Id, that is getting more complicated. You should search for other questions posed in the past on the XLS reading/parsing, I don't think it's worth to go deeper into this within this question (just because there should be available answers around).

Comment: To give a better answer, what you'd need to do maybe is:

- Create a Custom Object representing MyObjectLinkingToFile, having two properties/fields that reflects the 2 columns in the XLS (Related Record Id, and File URL)

- Use the std Salesforce import features to import the XLS into Salesforce

- Handle in a Trigger on the above Custom SObject what I've been suggesting before (or any other functional way you are abe to find in order to retrieve and load the remote file as an Attachment of the Related Record)

- You may delete all MyObjectLinkingToFile records after operations completed :)